# What is the meaning of 'covariant measure' in SLE?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading a paper related Schramm-Loewner Evolution.

The below is concrete link of the papaer.

https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2003-16-04/S0894-0347-03-00430-2/

In page 5, paper says,

"Suppose that µ is a measure on a measurable space Ω whose elements are subsets of a domain D. Suppose that Γ is a set of conformal transformations from subdomains D_0 ⊂ D onto D that is closed under composition. We say that µ is covariant under Γ (or Γ-covariant) if for all ϕ ∈ Γ, the measure µ restricted to the set ϕ−1(Ω) := {ϕ−1(K) : K ⊂ D} is equal to a constant Fϕ times the image
measure µ ◦ ϕ−1."

At this time, if T is the sigma-algebra, 'µ' is function from T ⊂ 2^(Ω) to R.

So I don't understand

"the measure µ restricted to the set ϕ−1(Ω) := {ϕ−1(K) : K ⊂ D}".

If what I understood is correct, the above means the value 'µ(ϕ−1(Ω))'.

Then, what is meaning of constant F_ϕ?

In short, I am having difficulty to understand the meaning of 'covariant under Γ (or Γ-covariant)'.

I wish you could teach me if possible.

Thank you for reading.